# How to make fields in redux-form be active by default?

Tags: redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I would like to make my redux-form fields 'active' by default. Is there a way to do this using RF v.6.5.0 ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment I don't think there is a property to set on refux-form `Field`s to set it to active by default. You can set it via refs once the component is mounted though.

Edit: Here might be a cleaner implementation using `getRenderedComponent()`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.defaultInput
    .getRenderedComponent()
    .focus()
}

<Field name="defaultInput" ref="defaultInput" withRef component="input"/>
```

[From redux-form Github](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1411#issuecomment-235833302) There are a few other examples and link in that Github issue.

Comment: attempted your solution as well as reading through the Redux-Form Github issue you referenced, but still unable to get it working. Used the code above verbatim however this.refs.defaultInput is undefined in componentDidMount.

Comment: Are you using a custom input component or a standard `input`?

Comment: Custom input. You can view the code I'm attempting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459190/how-to-use-react-refs-to-focus-a-redux-form-field

Comment: I see, can you post the custom input code either here and/or in the other question?