# How to use React refs to focus a Redux Form field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am trying to use React refs to focus a Redux-Form Field when it mounts.

When I try `this.refs.title.getRenderedComponent().focus()` in `componentDidMount`, an error is thrown saying:

`edit_fund.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRenderedComponent' of undefined`

When I console.log this.refs, it is mostly an empty object and sometimes identifies 'title' as being a ref, but it is not dependable.

Am I using refs incorrectly? My code is below for reference.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.refs.title
  .getRenderedComponent()
  .focus();
}
```

...

```
 <Field
    id="title"
    name="title"
    component={FormInput}
    type="text"
    ref="title" withRef
 />
```

Comment: This is weird, your code looks fine, please show the entire component code

Comment: have you solve this?

Comment: No, never solved it unfortunately.

Comment: I got something similar to this working *if* the component type is a simple type like `input`.  User defined components will yield refs, but they are not DOM elements that support calls like `focus()`.  Instead they are React elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try setting ref using callback function:

```
ref={(input) => { this.title = input; }}
```

and then use this to get underlying DOM node:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.title).focus();
```

of if DOM input element is wrapped in another element:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.title).getElementsByTagName("input")[0].focus()
```

According to React docs using refs with a string have some issues. Please check [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) for more details.

Comment: What if the redux form is defined in a functional component rather than a class?

Answer (score 0):

I use redux-form and [Material UI](https://material-ui.com) and had to do the following. `MaterialCheckboxField` and `MaterialTextField` are custom components in my project wrapping `material-ui/{Checkbox,TextField}`.

I converted `MaterialTextField` to a *class component* (as stipulated in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)).

> You may not use the `ref` attribute on *function* components because they **don’t have instances**.

```
import { findDOMNode } from "react-dom";
```

The field setting focus (within the `render()` method):

```
<Field
  component={MaterialCheckboxField}
  label="Checkbox"
  name="..."
  onClick={event => {
    if (!event.target.checked) return;
    // focus() field after grace period
    // oddity of Material UI, does not work without
    window.setTimeout(() => this.textField.focus(), 150);
  }}
/>
```

> **Material UI specific**
>   Suggestion to allow a grace period using `setTimeout()` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949394/how-to-set-focus-to-a-materialui-textfield). Consider @Lukas' comment:
>
> *"This code may throw. What would be even better is to save `setTimeout()` returned ID to component and on
>   `componentWillUnmount()` check if the timeout is still there and clear
>   it if so"*

The field that will receive focus (within the `render()` method):

```
<Field
  component={MaterialTextField}
  label="Text field"
  name="..."
  ref={ref => {
    const node = findDOMNode(ref);
    if (node) {
      // Material UI wraps input element, 
      // use querySelector() to obtain reference to it
      // if not using MUI, querySelector() likely not needed
      this.textField = node.querySelector("input");
    }
  }}
  withRef
/>
```

> **Note**
>   I am using Material UI `0.x`, not sure if that's why
>   `React.CreateRef()` didn't work for me (the recommended approach
>   [since React 16.3](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)).

Comment: I have tried  your solution It works but with that i am not able to next textbox it stuck on single input box. please help me.

Comment: const node = findDOMNode(refs);
                if (node) {
                    node.focus()
                }