# Pass forward ref through Redux Form?

Tags: redux-form, forward-reference

I'm using Redux Forms:

In Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.myRef);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>   
            <CustomField ref={this.ref} />
        </div>
    )
  }
```

In CustomField:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import Child from 'components/Child';
const CustomField = props => {
  return <Field {...props} component={Child} type="text" />;
};
```

I need to manage focus on the Child component from Parent. Normally you would use a forward ref but I'm not sure if this is possible with Redux Forms? The following is erroring and all the props are undefined:

```
const CustomField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <Field {...props} component={() => <Child {...props} ref={ref} />} type="text" />;
});
```

Message from the console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component supplied to Field.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the console?

Comment: I guess this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459190/how-to-use-react-refs-to-focus-a-redux-form-field

Comment: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the older syntax where you pass the ref as a normal prop. I think you have to call it something other than `ref`:

In Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.myRef);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>   
            <CustomField customRef={this.ref} />
        </div>
    )
  }
```

In CustomField:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import Child from 'components/Child';
const CustomField = props => {
  return <Field {...props} component={Child} type="text" />;
};
```

In Child (not sure if this needs to be a class or not):

```
class Child Extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <input ref={customRef}  />
    )
  }
}
```

The older style seems simpler to work with to me. As a tangential point it would be interesting if anyone could explain the downsides to it, as I assume there are some?